# finding all sites hosted on a nginx server

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

So is it possible to find out every single site (vhost) hosted on a nginx server ?

For example
Nginx config :

```
server {
listen  80;
server_name  domain1.com;
}
server {
listen  80;
server_name  domain2.com;
}
server {
listen  80;
server_name  domain3.com;
}
```

Is it possible for users to see all sites on the server ?

Comment: Obviously, just go read the nginx configuration.

Comment: Where in the documentation am i suppose to be looking ?

Comment: `cd $NGINX && grep -Ri server_name *`

Comment: To see just the active Sites:

    cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ && sudo grep -R "\ server_name\ " *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for users to see all sites on the server ?

No it is not possible unless users have access to the conf file(s).

Comment: Thanks for the information glad someone understood what i ment :P (my terrible descriptive skills) May also be at work.

Answer (score 2):

Either look in this file : /etc/nginx/nginx.conf or look at the files in this location /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Just depends how you have set you Nginx server up.